# TextView background black only on Galaxy devices

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-xml

On Galaxy S2 & S3's, my textview's background color is black while on every other device it's transparent, which is what I want.  How can I fix it so the textview is transparent on all devices?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:background="@drawable/descshape02"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:lines="1"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:paddingLeft="7dip"
        android:paddingRight="7dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15dip" >

        <requestFocus />
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And descshape02.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#070805"
        android:startColor="#B8833F"
        android:type="linear" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />

    <size
        android:height="30dp"
        android:width="270dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#877B10" />

</shape>
```

EDIT:

Ok so this could just be a bug in the emulator, but the reason I have a black background on Galaxy devices is due to the `shadowColor` attribute.  On all other devices the `shadowColor` attribute displays a glow around the text, on Galaxy devices, it's a solid color around the entire textview element.  Still not sure how to fix this, so any hacks or work-arounds would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by black or transparent background, when in your layout you are setting android:background="@drawable/descshape02" having brown to black gradient ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really see why that would do that. 
Are you using emulator ? 
If yes, in my opinion, it would just be emulator bug.

Comment: Yes this is showing in an emulator, but it seems odd that only Galaxy devices have this issue.  The text in the textview is scrolling above the gradient background, and on every other device the gradient background is the color I have set in my `<shape>` while on Galaxy devices, the text has a black background over the set gradient.  I'm at a loss, and I really hope this is just a bug in the emulator (using Genymotion emulator).

Comment: I really think it's about the emulator.
If you have a friend or family with Galaxy stuff, try it

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

for transparent background, or add an alpha channel to the beginning of your colors in your drawable you are using? Example with a very low opacity for alpha channel:

```
android:endColor="#33070805"
android:startColor="#33B8833F"
```